# How to hide console messages on shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, console

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with kernel version 2.6.38-020638-generic. On the shutdown process when the desktop wallpaper is gone, there is always a black console printing some messages and then the ubuntu loading screen (the same one when the ubuntu is starting). What I want is to hide the black console so that the purple ubuntu loading comes right after the desktop wallpaper is gone.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try editing /etc/init/rc.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/rc.conf
```

and comment console output so it looks like:

```
#console output
```

Don't touch anything else in the file!

Then reboot and it should no longer show anything.

If you want to know what this does do

```
man 5 init
```

and read on the console output section.

Comment: This doesn't work on 13.04 and 12.04. I still see lots of console messages always.

Comment: This worked for me on 13.04.

Comment: Any way to do this on 17.04?