# Console shows on shutdown/logout

Tags: 12.04, console, text

When I shut down, I will see a black screen with console text for about one second.  After about one second, it goes to the splash screen and shuts down normally.  I see the same console when I am log out.  Is this normal?  I am running 12.04.

Comment: What does the text says?

Comment: Please check-out [hide console on shutdown][1] maybe this helps.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39110/how-to-hide-console-messages-on-shutdown